# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un elemento undefined de mi array?

Tags: javascript

Buenas, he añadido un metodo al prototipo de array para limpiarlo de elementos indefinidos, pero por alguna razón no logro que funcione, aqui os lo dejo

```
Array.prototype.compacta = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i > this.length; i++){
        if(this[i] === undefined){
            this.splice(i , 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui os dejo el array y la llamada al metodo

```
var array = ['hola' , undefined , 'adios' , 'pepito', undefined,'sol'];
array.compacta();
window.console.log(array);
```

Por consola me muestra el array entero. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas, no me habia fijado en lo de i mayor a la longitud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu código solo tienes un error y es que en el ciclo `for` debes preguntar que la variable `i` sea menor a la cantidad de elementos del `array`, no que sea mayor:

```js
Array.prototype.compacta = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if(this[i] === undefined){
            this.splice(i , 1);
        }
    }
}

var array = ['hola' , undefined , 'adios' , 'pepito', undefined,'sol'];
array.compacta();
window.console.log(array);
```

Otra forma fácil y rápida de lograrlo es usar el método [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de **JavaScript**

```js
var array = ['hola' , undefined , 'adios' , 'pepito', undefined,'sol'];

array = array.filter(function(dato){
  return dato != undefined
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo este método, extendiendo el prototipo de Array nativo:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

test = new Array("", "One", "Two", "", "Three", "", "Four").clean("");
test2 = [1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];
test2.clean(undefined);
```

O simplemente puede empujar los elementos existentes en otra matriz:

```
// Eliminará todos los valores no requeridos: indefinido, nulo, 0, falso, NaN y "" (cadena vacía)
function cleanArray(actual) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
    if (actual[i]) {
      newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

cleanArray([1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías considerar recorrer desde el final del índice hasta el primero, asimismo, hacer uso de `typeof` para obtener si es del tipo `undefined`.

```js
Array.prototype.compacta = function(){
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--){
        if(typeof this[i] === 'undefined'){
            this.splice(i , 1);
        }
    }
}

var array = ['hola' , undefined , 'adios' , 'pepito', undefined,'sol'];
array.compacta();
window.console.log(array);
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Operador typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof)